# Use \DTLifoddrow in preamble

Tags: datatool, colortbl

I'm putting many tables in many files generated by csv files.
I'm using `datatools` (opposed to say `pgfplotstable`) because it is much more forgiving in terms of the csv input format (e.g. it ignores quotes around text).  However, I would like to make my tables "stripy" with a grey color every other row.

To put it plainly, I would like to use `\DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{grey}}{}` in the preamble of the document.  That way I can save myself from manually creating every tabular environment and can apply the same style to all tables.

Unfortunately `\DTLifoddrow` must be inside `\DTLforeach`.  Therefore I might have to redefine `\DTLforeach` or `\DTLdisplaydb` to automatically add my `\DTLifoddrow`.  I'm not sure which path to take or how to go about redefining these commands.

Comment: Note: I do not know how many rows or columns there are (or their labels). The input data changes for every table.  The idea here is to make "stripy tables" a global thing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). This helps us to provide an answer for you.

Comment: You're probably right - I should have. But I just found the answer to my question! Unfortunately, can't answer my own question with so little rep.  I had to use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\rowcolors{1}{green}{blue}` (or whatever).  Both of these can go in the preamble and will be applied 'globally'.

Comment: That's great! Are you sure you can not answer? I thought this is possible with rep 1.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours before answering my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since asking, I've figured out how to do a lot of fun things with datatool:

### Short Answer

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{0}{white}{light-gray}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}
```

Every tabular environment (including those created automatically by DTL) is now striped. To draw an tabular not striped use `\begin{oldtabular}` and `\end{oldtabular}`.

## Fun Stuff

### Automatically Use Booktabs

Booktabs are (is?) wonderful. Use it always.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
% start every dtl table with \toprule from booktabs
\renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}

% likewise for \midrule and \bottomrule from booktabs 
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}
```

Now all datatool tables look nice!

### Formatting Numbers

My CSV files tend to look like `4525,25463135,2346234,4643` etc. (i.e. *ugly*). There's no need for datatool to display them poorly also. Use package `siunitx`!

Now I must admit, I do not know all the power of `siunitx`, so I recommend reading docs, but I'll tell you what I do know.

We're going to use it to format long numbers to have commas at the thousands places (i.e. 1,234 instead of 1234). For very long numbers I *think* `siunitx` will put the number in scientific notation. With some tweaks, it is also possible to display (or round to) any number of decimal places. Again, please read the docs.

In order for `siunitx` to work it's magic, every number must be wrapped in `\num{ }`. We do this in the following way:

```
% package to automatically format numbers with thousands separator
\usepackage[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=3]{siunitx}
\renewcommand*{\dtlrealformat}[1]{\num{#1}}
```

This should correctly format anything that appears to be a number (according to `datatool`).

### Easy CSV Inserting

We define two commands: `\csvtable` and `\widecsvtable`:

```
\newcommand{\csvtable}[3][]{%
    \DTLloadrawdb[#1]{#2}{#2}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{#3}
        \DTLdisplaydb{#2}
    \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\widecsvtable}[3][]{%
    \DTLloadrawdb[#1]{#2}{#2}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{#3}
        \begin{adjustbox}{center}
            {\footnotesize \DTLdisplaydb{#2}}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
}
```

`\csvtable` takes the form `\csvtable[options]{filename}{caption}` were `options` are the same options you would supply to `\DTLloadrawdb`.  For example,
column labels *in the csv file* must be unique and cannot contain any
LaTeX special symbols. To set column labels without any restrictions
use e.g.:

```
\csvtable[headers={repeat header,repeat header,\$ymbol}]{file.csv}{caption}
```

where `headers=` a comma separated list of column labels.
If the csv file does not contain labels as the first row, use option `noheader`
e.g.:

```
\csvtable[noheader,headers={*header list*}]{file.csv}{caption}
```

`\widecsvtable` is used the same way and simply shrinks the font of the table and centers it on the *page*. This gives you room for an extra column or two. To use this we need to `\usepackage{adjustbox}`.

### Multi-Line Column Headers

In general (not just in tables), words can be stacked on top of each other with
`\shortstack{row 1\\row 2}`.  This is useful for multi line column headers e.g.:

```
\csvtable[headers={\shortstack{line 1\\line 2},\shortstack{line 1\\line 2}}]{file.csv}{caption}
```

is a two column table with (possibly long) two-line column labels.

## Long Answer

Putting it all together, you'll end up with a preamble that looks something like this:

```
% import xcolor and (optionally) booktabs and adjustbox
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% package to automatically format numbers with thousands separator
\usepackage[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=3]{siunitx}

% datatool
\usepackage{datatool}

% wrap all real numbers with \num from siunitx so that they're
% displayed nicely
\renewcommand*{\dtlrealformat}[1]{\num{#1}}

% start every dtl table with \toprule from booktabs
\renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}

% likewise for \midrule and \botomrule from booktabs 
% (take this out if you dont like booktabs, but it is _highly_ recommended)
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}

% here's where the magic happens
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{0}{white}{light-gray}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}



\newcommand{\csvtable}[3][]{%
    \DTLloadrawdb[#1]{#2}{#2}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{#3}
        \DTLdisplaydb{#2}
    \end{table}
}

\newcommand{\widecsvtable}[3][]{%
    \DTLloadrawdb[#1]{#2}{#2}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{#3}
        \begin{adjustbox}{center}
            {\footnotesize \DTLdisplaydb{#2}}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
}
```